# How do I make it so that a class inside of another class doesn't have to be instantiated to be accessed by `Class1.Class2.Method()`

Tags: c#

How do I make it so that, if i have this class:

```cs
namespace RSA_Functions
{
    internal class Crypto
    {
        internal Encrypt encrypt;
        internal Decrypt decrypt;

        private RSAParameters privateKey;
        private RSAParameters publicKey;
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider csp;

        //Generates public and private keys
        internal void GenerateKeys()
        {
            csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

            //private key
            privateKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);

            //public key
            publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

            csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        }

        internal class Encrypt
        {
            internal static string String(string plainTextData, bool returnString)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static Byte[] String(string plainTextData)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static string Byte(byte[] bytesToEncrypt, bool returnString)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static Byte[] Byte(byte[] bytesToEncrypt)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
        }

        internal class Decrypt
        {
            internal static string Byte(byte[] bytesEncrypted, bool returnString)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static byte[] Byte(byte[] bytesEncrypted)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static string String(string stringEncrypted, bool returnString)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
            internal static byte[] String(string stringEncrypted)
            {
                //Bla bla bla
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that I can simply do `Crypto crypto = new()` and be able to access the Ecrypt and Decrypt classes methods with a simple `crypto.GenerateKeys(); crypto.Encrypt.String("a random string");` and not have to instantiate Encrypt and Decrypt in order to access the methods inside of them. Do I use something other than a class to contain them or?

Answer (score 0):

As starting point I recommend using `interfaces` or `abstract` classes.
For example

```
interface Encrypt
{
   void DoEncrypt();
}
interface Decrypt
{
   void DoDecrypt();
}
public class MyClass: Encrypt, Decrypt
{
  // declare interfaces methods
}
```

Of course this is not a tested example, it's just to show you what an starting point would be.
Using interfaces will force you to code the interface methods inside the main class (implement interface methods)

Another way is using inheritance

```
class Encrypt{
   
   public void DoSomeThing()
   {
      // ...
   }
}
class MyClass:Encrypt
{
   public MyClass()
   {
     this.DoSomeThing();
   }
}
```

But the use of inheritance has a native limitation in C#. You will only be able to inherit for exactly one parent class. That's why I recommend interfaces. The use of abstract classes has the same limitation as the use of normal classes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it probably makes no sense to add your `Crypto` class initialization logic into separate method. Consider to remove method `void GenerateKeys()` and place its code into `Crypto` class constructor:

```
internal class Crypto
{
   // private fields
   //...
   internal Encrypt encrypt;
   internal Decrypt decrypt;
   
   // constructor    
   internal Crypto()
   {
      // your GenerateKeys() code
   }

   // ...
}
```

Then, in your approach you can add this code to constructor, so your `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` instances are created along with the `Crypto` instance:

```
encrypt = new Encrypt();
decrypt = new Decrypt();
```

Finally, remove modifier `static` from your `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` methods definition to call these methods via class instances and to be able to use your non-static fields in its code.

Also consider to refactor method names in you `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` classes to match [c# coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions):

```
internal class Encrypt
{
   internal string GetString(string plainTextData)
   {
   }

   internal Byte[] GetBytes(string plainTextData)
   {
   }

   internal string GetString(byte[] bytesToEncrypt)
   {
   }

   internal Byte[] GetBytes(byte[] bytesToEncrypt)
   {
   }
}

// same for Decrypt class
```